# Accessing patch through coordinates stored in a list

Tags: netlogo

I have a list which is storing the list of coordinates of patches.

```
let coor [ [0 1] [ 1 0] [1 -1] ]
```

Now I want to ask the patch at the location of the 2nd element of the list to change its color to red.

```
ask patch (item 1 coor) [ set pcolor red ]
```

This gives an error that patch expects a number instead of a list or block. How to make NetLogo understand that the (item 1 coor) is a set of two numbers?

Any other way to approach this? I have also tried using 'table' extension for this but there also same issue was coming.

Comment: One workaround is to store the first and second coordinates in separate lists, say x_cor & y_cor.

ask patch (item 1 x_cor) (item 1 y_cor) [ set pcolor red ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an appropriate reporter:

```
to-report patch-at-xy [#xy]
  let _x item 0 #xy
  let _y item 1 #xy
  report patch _x _y
end
```

This requires a tiny change in your code above:

```
to test
  let coor [ [0 1] [ 1 0] [1 -1] ]
  ask patch-at-xy (item 1 coor) [ set pcolor red ] 
end
```

That said, you almost certainly should be storing a list of patches rather than of their coordinates.