# Finding neighbors of elements of a cyclic array without using mod

Tags: netlogo

I have an array having six elements which have cyclic nature, i.e. the neighbors of the first element are the 2nd element and 6th element, and similarly the neighbors of the 6th element are the 5th and 1st element. Now one simple way to access them is:

```
array:item array ( (a + 5) mod 6 ) and array:item array ( (a + 1) mod 6)
```

where 'a' is the array element we are interested in. 
Considering the fact that 'mod'operator is computationally costliest, how can I implement the cyclic nature of array without using 'mod' operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Premature optimization?  I doubt `mod` will be your bottle neck.
2. Just make a table (using the `table` extension) mapping each item to its "neighbors".

Comment: Thanks @Alan. I was having [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276117/accessing-patch-through-coordinates-stored-in-a-list) with using tables. Now that also has been answered by you, I would give it a shot. Earlier I used two lists, as in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276117/accessing-patch-through-coordinates-stored-in-a-list). 
Can you elaborate more on premature optimization or give some links? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."
Knuth, "Structured Programming with Goto Statements". Computing Surveys 6:4 (December 1974), pp. 261–301, §1.